# AWS Ubuntu tomcat not connection from web browser on 8080

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run one a ubuntu instance in AWS. After startup the tomcat server, but I cant access it via public network.

```
 netstat -atnp |grep LISTEN
```

By checking it.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10532/java
```

And the security I set to all allow all.

```
All traffic
All
All
0.0.0.0/0
```

Is it anything i am missing? Thank :d

Answer (score 1):

If you are running it in VPC - ensure you have attached an Elastic IP to the Instance and have connected the Internet gateway to the subnet where the instance is placed.

If above is set; ensure that your ip tables is switched off.

Answer (score 0):

First of all It is not clear what you mean by not accessible are you asking about SSH or browser access

So assuming SSH

1. First Check your security group attached to your Ec2 contains required port open to public.
2. check if you instance has a public IP assigned to it .

ssh 22 and browser access 80 should be open to 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0